# SharePoint 2016 Intranet performance issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, performance

We have multi server SharePoint 2016 farm which consist of 2 WFE, 1 APP, 1 Search and 1 DB. SharePoint Home page (publishing pages with variations) takes longer time to open when request is pass through one of WFE. All installation has been done through Min role and status is compliant. Some of ULS and even logs:

Event Log:

> The program w3wp.exe, with the assigned process ID 8444, could not
>   authenticate locally by using the target name HTTP/portal.com The
>   target name used is not valid. A target name should refer to one of
>   the local computer names, for example, the DNS host name. Try a
>   different target name.

ULS Logs:

> 0x4224 
>   SharePoint Foundation                 User Key
>   ayswe   Unexpected       Could not get SPWeb so could not get user
>   key.                348dd59d-4baf-80d5-28a6-d323168488d4

There were logs related to Distributed cache too.

Comment: Do you have BLOBCache enabled? Any reason you don't go with App+Search for your two back end server so you get high availability in service apps which run there as well as Search?

Comment: Are the errors only showing up on one of the two web front end servers, or on both of them?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Tried enabling distributed cache,But min role is showing non compliant and subsequently getting removed.I think separate search is better for better performance due to high availability of resources

Comment: @AndyDawson Errors are showing on both WFE.Site is taking longer time to open, if it passed through a particular WFE,Other WFE is responding well.

Comment: @user7335324 convert your FEs into DistributedCache+WebFrontEnd servers. And your backends into App+Search. This way your workloads are highly available across the farm.

Comment: @Rajnish what have you done to resolve the issue? Btw: I expect the attempt of Trevor will not have solved it, does it? Seems to be more like a authentication problem. In my experience having App and Search on one machine slows all service applications down if several content sources are doing full crawls enormously.

Comment: @PhilFancy issue was with infrastructure only and we did some latest windows update on LDAP servers and it started working.